# Java - List all connections

Tags: java, list, connection

I'm writing a java Server(multithreaded)/Client chat for educational purposes.

What is the best way to list all the connections (ip) from Server side?

My Java knowledge is pretty basic :)

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure that you should try to write this, given that "basic knowledge? Is listing those connections your last and least problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please consult the [help File](http:stack overflow.com/help) and acquaint yourself with the proper format for asking useful questions that will receive answers. Stack Overflow is meant for asking for help with specific programming issues, as opposed to tutorial information that an Internet search would yield.

Answer (score 0):

Under linux, you can use `netstat -a` to list all open TCP connections.

Answer (score 0):

In your server accept thread, when a client connects you should add the client's IP to a List array so you can refer to it later. This is useful because you can also iterate through the array for interface things like tables.